# Flutter Dart on windows 10

Tags: flutter, dart

When I am running any command that uses dart the response is always as follows;

```
building flutter tool... 
Running  Pub upgrade... 
The current Dart SDK version is 2.10.0-0.0.dev.flutter-9dca49e71e.

Because flutter_tools depends on collection >=1.15.0-nnbd <1.15.0-nullsafety.2 which requires SDK version >=2.9.0-18.0 <=2.9.10, version solving failed.
```

I am not able to switch the version nor the channel as those commands run through the same response.
I tried to uninstall flutter and dart, but I have only gotten back to the same issues.

Any help?

Comment: Please share your `pubspec.yaml`.

Comment: Hi also going encountering this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to where to your flutter install directory e.g. `C:\Tools\Flutter` and do a `git pull`.

After that you should be able to run any command, such as `flutter --help` and the Dart SDK will be on the correct version.

This can be verified by running `flutter upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to update my Path ENV Variable

Comment: can you be specific? what exactly did you change to get this fixed?

Comment: Interested in too. Have same problem